# Scala Actor with multiple Channels

Tags: scala

I have an actor that can process mesages of different types, I'm trying to use Channel for type safety:

```
import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._

case class Message(msg: String)

class FirstActor extends Actor {

  val Chan1 = new Channel[String](this)
  val Chan2 = new Channel[Int](this)

  def act() {

    loop {

        react {
                case Chan1 ! msg => println("message channel1=" + msg); sender ! None
                case Chan2 ! num => println("number channel2=" + num); sender ! None
        }
    }

  }  

}
```

However, the compile complains:

```
<console>:46: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.actors.Channel[String]
 required: scala.actors.Channel[Any]
Note: String <: Any, but class Channel is invariant in type Msg.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
           case Chan1 ! msg => println("message channel1=" + msg); sender ! None
```

I have tried `.asInstanceOf[Channel[Any]]`, but it seems the pattern never matches

What is the proper way to use multiple channels inside an Actor?

I'm using scala 2.9

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the channels. Try something like this:

```
react{
  case str: String => handleString(str)
  case i: Int => handleInt(i)
  case _ => println(this+": wrong message")
}
```

Obviously handleString and handleInt are some private function you should define.

Comment: I want channels for type safety

Comment: This approach is completely type safe.

Comment: static typing. Channels are restricted to receiving only messages of its typing, where as I can send any type of message to your actor. Channel will also make your code easier to read.

Comment: IMO my code is a lot easier to read, and I can send your actor any type of message too. Handle methods restrict the type of arguments just like the channels restrict the messages

Comment: with Channels, you send messages to the Channel, instead of sending it directly to the actor, so you can't accidentally send a Int to a Channel that expects String.

Comment: Also, your code maybe ok to read, but what if the user of your library does not have your source code? Its better to define the Channels in a trait that extends an Actor. Please, before you speak, read the question properly, think, and then post an answer - if you even have an answer